# Displayin relative information depending upon form field

Tags: php, forms, concrete5, form-processing

OK, Im working on an ordering system. When the user logs in they are presented with a list of vendors along with that vendors address and so on. Then under each vendor is a list of their product and box where they can input the quanity of each product they want.

I know how i can pass the quanity to the next page but im having trouble figuring out how im going to pass the vendor information for where the order is associated 
for instance if they placed an order for 25 of something for one vendor then on the confirm page it would put the quanity and diplay the vendor for which the order is associated.

My code is below. Any help will obviously be greatly appreciated and there's a chance i'll let you name my first born. Assuming i ever have kids and that's a big assumption.

```
<form name="OrderForm" action="/confirm" method="POST">
    <?php $query = 'SELECT * FROM Vendors WHERE VendorID = 1';
        $productquery = 'SELECT * FROM Products WHERE VendorID =  1';
$results = $db->getAll($query);
$productresults = $db->getAll($productquery);?>
 <table class="table">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Quantity/Product</th>
                  <th>Category</th>
                  <th>Vendor</th>
                  <th>Address</th>
                </tr>
<?php

foreach ($results as $vendor) {
?>
<tr class="category">
    <td></td>
    <td><?php echo $vendor['Category'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $vendor['Vendor'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $vendor['Address'];?></td>

    </tr> 
    <?php

 foreach ($productresults as $product){
    ?>

     <tr class="product">
    <td colspan="4"><span class="name"><input type="text" name="quantities[]" size="1" /><?php echo $product['Product'];?></span></td>

    </tr>
    </table>
<input type="submit" value="Checkout"<button style="float:right;" type="button" class="btn btn-primary"></button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you link them to the next page, use something like `orderpage.php?vendor=$vendor[vendor]` or the vendor ID, so you can grab the vendor info from the next page. 
You can do it like this:

`<td><a href="orderpage.php?vendor=<?php echo $vendor['Vendor'];"?>>
<?php echo $vendor['Vendor'];?>
</td></a>`

In order to get the vendor value from the url, you do the following:

`$vendor = $_GET['vendor'];`

And you will have the necessary information to run a query and grab all the vendor info. That's the easiest way.

IMPORTANT: Make sure to filter `$vendor` variable appropriately, as users can and will try to mess with it by adding code after `?vendor=`, so depending on what value you want to pass (id number, special character, vendor name etc) filter the `$_GET['vendor']` so only your information can be passed to the query.